# superscript bug

Tags: equations

I don't know if you guys can help me here but I do subscript when a value is superscripted then it isn't showed in the right way? 2 shouldn't be shown under `x` but more like `x_2`

my code looks like this :

```
\begin{align*}
\frac{y_2}{y_2}=\frac{b*a^x_2}{b*a^x_1}&=a^{x_2-x_1}=\sqrt[x_2-x_1]{\frac{y_2}{y_2}}
\end{align*}
```

[image: equation]

Comment: Do you just want `a^{x_2}`, etc. so that the whole of `x_2` is in the superscript?

Comment: well x is super scriptes and 2 is sub scripted so it will be a^{x_{2}} before it did work (figured it out but I can't give an anwser yet

Comment: note `a^x_2` is exactly the same as `a_2^x` that is an a with a subscript 2 and a superscript x, it is not `a^{x_2}` which is a with a superscript of x sub 2

Answer (score 4):

Just replace `\frac{b*a^x_2}{b*a^x_1}` with `\frac{b*a^{x_2}}{b*a^{x_1}}`.